# fstream library, trying to create a file with variable name (c++)

Tags: c++, file, fstream

i am trying to create a file whose name is tied to a string type variable, however when i try to run it, i get this error --[Error] no match for call to '(std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream}) (const char*)'

Here is the code:

```
void Crear()
{   
    string nombre;
    ofstream output;
    ifstream input;

    cout << "Deme el nombre de su archivo: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, nombre);

    //this is where the error happens
    output(nombre.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement:

```
output(nombre.c_str());
```

The compiler thinks that `output` is a "callable" but std::fstream didn't overload call operator. So you get compile-time error.

To fix it; you either call the member `open`:

```
    output.open(nomber); // directly because the new standard allows strings for fstream::open
```

or when initializing `output`:

```
std::ofstream output(nombere); // (contructor of ofstream that takes std::string) or 
std::ofstream output(nombere.c_str()); // ctor that takes const char*
```